# Random time Swift

Tags: iphone, swift2

So when a UIButton is pressed I want a random 1 of 4 images to pop up but I want one of the images to pop up at a random time after the button has been pressed. I'm using Xcode and swift 2. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So when I click my fingers I want a brand new bmw to pop up... StackOverflow don't write code for you.  What have you tried already?

Comment: @LukePark I tried to set a variable to ark4random_uniform(5) and then if the var is equal to one of the numbers it will display the corresponding image but that doesn't address the random time and I've never understood NSTimer.

Comment: What don't you understand about NSTimer?

Comment: @LukePark Every time I try to use it and with any tutorial I follow it never works

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need NSTimer (and all the tricky selector based stuff) at all. With help of matt's delay function (somewhere in stackowerflow, i am lazy to find the link :-), it could be as simple as

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func randomDelay(range: Range<UInt32>, completion: ()->()) {
    if let first = range.first,
        let last = range.last {
        let d = arc4random_uniform(last) + first
        print("now:     ",NSDate(),"delay:",d)
        delay(Double(d)) {
            completion()
        }
    }
}

let range:Range<UInt32> = 3..<10

// run this on button press
randomDelay(range) {
    // update your image here
    print("complete:", NSDate())
}
```

it prints something like

```
now:      2016-04-02 07:33:24 +0000 delay: 9
complete: 2016-04-02 07:33:34 +0000
```

and on another 'press'

```
now:      2016-04-02 07:39:55 +0000 delay: 5
complete: 2016-04-02 07:40:00 +0000
```